# How to append a delete button to a comment with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to JavaScript so I apologize in advance for this question! It's still hard for me to 'read' where I am going wrong.
I am trying to practice simple logic where there is a form with two inputs. Then, what is typed into the input is appended to the page after the person presses submit on the form. The person's inputs are structured as `li` being added to a `ul`.

I can make this part work fine on its own. However, I am trying to append not just an li, but a delete button with each `li`. Then, I want the delete button to be able to delete its associated `li`.

Here is my logic, but I know it is not right...

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const list = document.querySelector('#list');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let product = form.elements.product;
  let qty = form.elements.qty;
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const button = document.createElement('button')
  li.innerText = `${product.value} ${qty.value}`;
  button.textContent = "Delete"
  li.appendChild('button')
  list.appendChild(li);
  product.value = '';
  qty.value = '';
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    e.target.remove
  })
})
```

```html
<h1>Grocery List</h1>
<form action="/nowhere">
  <label for="item">Enter A Product</label>
  <input type="text" id="product" name="product">
  <label for="item">Enter A Quantity</label>
  <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<ul id="list"></ul>
<li>Test</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors, missing () and missing (e)

Too many quotes ('button') and you do not want to delete the target, but its containing `li`

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const product = document.getElementById('product');
const quantity = document.getElementById('qty');


form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const prd = product.value,
    qty = +quantity.value; // cast to number
  if (prd === "" || qty === 0) return; // nothing to add
  product.value = '';
  quantity.value = '';

  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const delBut = document.createElement('button')
  li.innerText = `${prd} ${qty}`;
  delBut.textContent = "Delete"
  li.appendChild(delBut)
  list.appendChild(li);
  delBut.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.closest('li').remove()
  })
})
```

```html
<h1>Grocery List</h1>
<form action="/nowhere">
  <label for="item">Enter A Product</label>
  <input type="text" id="product" name="product">
  <label for="item">Enter A Quantity</label>
  <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, I knew it would be simple to someone more experienced

Comment: I added a test for content

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need ' ' creating an element but, DON't want ' ' when appending it?

Comment: button is the button object, 'button' is the tag name

Comment: Ohhh gotcha. I didn't name my variable well!

Comment: I renamed the button for clarity

Comment: I actually moved all consts and use getElementById where useful